# How to use as much RAM as possible for my program?

Tags: c, winapi, memory-management, ram

I am striving to maximize speed of my program (in order to get results in real-time) and avoid unnecessary loading of data from hard drive.

Program is supposed to process a huge amount of images and I would like to handle in RAM as much processed data as possible. But I found out that `malloc` won't allocate more than 2GB even when I'm having 8GB of RAM (Windows 7 64-bit).

How can I make my program use as much RAM as possible?

Comment: If you switch to a 64-bits Linux you will be able to `malloc` much more than 2GB (probably nearly 7 or 8GB).

Comment: Remember that e.g. `malloc` allocates a continuous block of memory. It might simply be that there is no block big enough for you. Also remember that even if you have 8GB of physical RAM, all applications share that memory, and unless you continuously read/write all of the memory then parts of it might be swapped out to disk.

Comment: Are you sure your program is compiled in 64 bits mode into a 64 bits executable?

Comment: Thought - can you not just keep a nice buffer queue of images and keep it topped-up with data from the drive, (ie. with a read thread)?  I mean, sounds like XY problem to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the windows equivalent of `mmap(2)` is [**`VirtualAlloc`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

This should allow you to use a lot more memory. Please keep in mind that the OS may still decide to page out your memory. You can lock it in RAM with [**`VirtualLock`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366895%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The amount of lockable memory may be limited though.

Also as mentioned in the comments make sure to compile your program as 64-bit.

Comment: _"The amount of lockable memory may be limited"_ -- yes, and it not only _may be_ but it _is very seriously_ limited. The default, if I remember correctly, is 16 MiB, unless you adjust your working set size first.